# EBNF grammar definitions for PHP?

Tags: php, grammar, ebnf

I am wondering if someone has compiled an EBNF for PHP somewhere. I found both [this site](http://www.icosaedro.it/articoli/php-syntax.html) and [this site](http://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=129389890703226&w=2). Both seem like they are incomplete, though. [This question is very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680119/php-language-specification), but it's a year old. I would like to know if there has been any progress made.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may want to have a look at the [yacc grammar PHP uses internally](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_language_parser.y). I know, it's not EBNF, but maybe it's okay for your needs.

You may also want to look at the [re2c lexer definition](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_language_scanner.l).

Comment: The link to the grammar seems broken, but I think the file is also on [GitHub](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_language_parser.y).

Comment: This awkward moment when php language has a specification, while typescript [does not](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15711)...

Answer (score 8):

The [site](http://www.icosaedro.it/articoli/php-syntax.html) from which I've taken the following links is in italian but we have:

- [php-syntax-yacc.txt](http://www.icosaedro.it/articoli/php-syntax-yacc.txt)
- [php-syntax-ebnf.txt](http://www.icosaedro.it/articoli/php-syntax-ebnf.txt)

Comment: Hi,
Do you think the EBNF specification is complete?

Comment: It's a quote old post, I cannot say honestly. Don't think so

Comment: yeah very old indeed ;) Thanks for the response

Answer (score 2):

ANTLR 4 PHP grammar is also available: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/php.

### Features

- Heterogeneous code processing ([islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_grammar)):

  - HTML
  - Script
  - CSS
  - PHP
  - Heredoc
- [Alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).
- [Heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).
- [Interpolation strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple) (but not fully covered).
- aspTags.
- Improved lexer error processing with artificial string fragments
  (for example double closed quote at the end: `<div attr='value'' />`).

### Testing

Grammar has been tested (parsing without errors) on the following projects:

- [phpBB-3.1.6](https://github.com/phpbb/phpbb/archive/release-3.1.6.zip)
- [ZendFramework-2.4.8](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/archive/release-2.4.8.zip)

Also, this parser has been tested on plenty number of PHP files from different CMS (~70000 files).

Answer (score 0):

An ANTLR3 grammar is available her:

```
  http://code.google.com/p/phpparser/
```

The above grammar isn't compatible with [ANTLR4](http://www.antlr.org/about.html), the current ANTLR release.